# How to handle an optional value associated with UILabel.text - swift

Tags: ios, swift, observer-pattern

I have a single view application.  The UIViewController uploads a file and a second UIViewController acts as a custom popup.  The first viewcontroller sends notifications on the progress of the upload to an observer in the popup.  My application crashes randomly in the second viewcontroller in the line indicated below.  I do not know how to handle the unwrapping of this options value

custom popup UIViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtLabelOutlet: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createUploadFinishObserver()
}


 func createUploadObserver(){
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: notifcationName, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in

        guard
            var arrayN = notification.userInfo as? [String:Double],
            let num = arrayN["progress"] else{
                print("no valid data")
                return
        }
        // UPDATE PROGRESS BAR
        let progress = Float.init(num)
        self.progressOutlet.progress = progress

        // UPDATE LABEL
        let percent = Int(progress*100)

        if self.txtLabelOutlet.text != nil{
            self.txtLabelOutlet.text = "\(percent)%" // CRASHES HERE 'Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to find out what is nil.

Comment: the problem looks like you may not have linked the outlet to the code if it's crashing when setting the textLabel, it probably means that the 'txtLabelOutlet' is nil, thus it isn't connected. Just a thought!

Comment: Also what does “a second UIViewController acts as a custom popup” mean?

Comment: Looking at your code there doesn't seem to be a reason why `percent` should be `nil`, yet that seems the only possible reason for the crash. o.O

Comment: try to print `percent` before displaying there might be a `nil` value

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your label property doesn't exist yet. Are you sure it is connected to the one in your storyboard?

If you open the assistant editor while in your story board, you can drag from the bubbles beside your outlet into your view.

[image]

Comment: So how do you explain that we passed the condition test `if self.txtLabelOutlet.text != nil`?

Comment: Gremlins. Definitely.